# Is there an endomorphism of an elliptic curve which is not induced by an ambient endomorphism...?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve, and think of it as sitting in $P^2$. Is there an endomorphism $f : E \to E$ which is does not extend to a birational endomorphism $P^2 \to P^2$?

What about the multiplication maps in particular? (My suspicion is that these do extend, because one can write them down as polynomials or something, but I am not completely sure.)

I know that if $f$ is an isomorphism, then it is actually a linear automorphism of $P^2$.

If I was asking for rational maps, it would be obvious that asking it to be defined everywhere on $P^2$ is too much to ask for, since we can move the codimension 2 locus of indeterminacy away from the elliptic curve. But I am not sure what maps from projective space to an elliptic curve look like. I guess I would be interested in an answer to that as well.

More generally, I am wondering about situations where maps defined on closed subvarieties of projective space may not extend to maps defined on open subsets of projective space. It seems that in principal such a thing should be possible, simply because the there may be more line bundles along that variety, but I am not sure. I would like a concrete example.

Thanks!

Comment: I am quite late but I would like to know any reference for the fact that isomorphisms are induced from projective plane.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer:

"But I am not sure what maps from projective space to an elliptic curve look like."

1. There are no non-constant rational maps from $P^n$ to an elliptic curve. This is because the existence of such a map would allow one to pullback the holomorphic differential to a holomorphic differential. (A priori it is only a rational differential, but because the non-regularity locus of the map is codimension $\geq 2$, the differential is regular everywhere on the compliment of a codimension 2 set, and therefore the divisor of poles of that differential is empty, so the differential is actually regular. The general fact is that rational maps to projective varieties induce injections on the spaces of global holomorphic differentials.) This contradicts the fact that the space of holomorphic 1-forms on $P^n$ has dimension zero.

So this at least gives some morphisms defined on closed subsets that do not extend to even a rational map. (The identity map from an embedded elliptic curve to itself.)